# A Python3.5 pacakge for MS SQL similar to psycopg2

Tags: python, sql-server

Can anyone suggest a python 3.5 compatible package for MS SQL that is similar to psycopg2 for postgres?

Specifically looking to have multiple cursors doing multiple inserts/updates, per the psycopg2 pypi docs "It [psycopg2] was designed for heavily multi-threaded applications that create and destroy lots of cursors and make a large number of concurrent “INSERT”s or “UPDATE”s." (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psycopg2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use "pymssql,pyodbc" which are similar to psycopg2

Comment: I should have phrased this a bit better, so far I'm seeing that both have limitations when it comes to sharing a connection among several threads and pulling multiple cursors. (Generally throwing exceptions that specify that the "Connection is busy with results for another command". 

I'll confirm and rephrase the original question. Thank you for the reply though.